# Do I need to drain engine oil as per manufacuters recommended kms

Tags: car, oil-change

I drive my car very rarely say around 1500 to 2000 kms annually.  Do I still need to drain the engine oil as per manufacturer's recommendation of 10k kms or 6 months whichever comes first.

Comment: If you have a warranty, I would. Otherwise, I do yearly oil changes on my vehicle that doesn't get driven much.

Comment: 6 months??? Seriously? - Not sure I ever saw anything less than 24 months specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can send in your oil to a company for a used oil analysis which will tell you the state of your oil when you change it as well as various metallic ppm and what they mean for engine wear. You're using km and don't have a country listed in your profile, but you're looking for something like [Blackstone](http://www.blackstone-labs.com/).

Comment: The "or 6 months" exists for a reason too. The additives in the oil break down over time, regardless of how much the oil is used. Oil changes are cheap. Follow what the manual says.

Comment: @Spivonious by far the most sensible point made so far - you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oil change must be based on the engine performance. So specifically, it must be done based on the miles the vehicle covers.

Comment: There is something as such as a half life. Thats when the chemical additives which aid the engine in lubrication expire. Which is why the manufacturer claims to renew the cycle half yearly.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: motor oil contains additives that break down over time, regardless of heating/cooling cycles. Follow the recommendations. Oil changes are cheap.